# Passing Acess to Panel Control

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

So I have two forms. On form 1, I have created a panel called panel1. My question is if it is possible to pass control over to another form and add controls from the other form. Here is what my current code looks like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Control AccessPanel
    {
        get { return panel1; }
        set { panel1.Controls.Add(value); }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainForm = this.MainForm;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.MainForm.AccessPanel1.Controls.Add(/*Some Control*/)
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate a point in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what is the problem with the current code? (Apart that it has strange things like `MainForm = this.MainForm;` which does absolutely nothing and a property whose getter and setter do not get and set the same thing.)

Comment: The code doesn't add any controls for my panel1 and I need a help figuring out a method that does. I am very new to Winforms and I am confused on how to work with controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that `Form1` is the main form and `Form2` another form that is opened from the main form (probably a dialog). And also let's assume that `Form2` wants to add controls to a panel on the first form. Then `Form2` needs a reference to the first form. You can pass one in the constructor:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{                           
    private Form1 _form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.AddControl(/*Some Control*/); 
    }
}
```

I would not make the panel itself public. `Form2` should know as few as possible about `Form1`. This creates less dependencies between the forms.

In `Form1` I would add this method

```
public void AddControl(Control control)
{
    panel1.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

In `Form1` you can open `Form2` like this:

```
var form2 = new Form2(this); // Pass Form1 through the constructor.
form2.Show(this); // Here `this` is the owner.
                  // It ensures that Form2 always stays on top of Form1.
```

Or use `ShowDialog`.